# Make code for multiple textbox when press Enter send command Tab better

Tags: c#, tabs, textbox, keypress, enter

i already have code when user press key Enter on keyboard, it return tab and "jump" to next field, its working great, its possible make it for 2 or 3 textbox, problem when need make it on multiple textbox like 20 textbox for each form, its just not work.

See code:

```
// Detect if Enter key is pressed on each text box, mute sound enter "ding"  sound and replace Enter for tab (problem that have make it for each textbox)
        private void txtAltura_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true; //Silenciar Enter
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

        private void txtLargura_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true; //Silenciar Enter
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

        private void txtProfundidade_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true; //Silenciar Enter
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

//execute keypress command when enter is typed on textbox 
    private void txtProfundidade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtProfundidade.Text != "") { foreach (char c in txtProfundidade.Text.ToCharArray()) txtProfundidade_KeyPress(sender, new KeyPressEventArgs(c)); }

            }

            private void txtLargura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtLargura.Text != "") { foreach (char c in txtLargura.Text.ToCharArray()) txtLargura_KeyPress(sender, new KeyPressEventArgs(c)); }
            }

            private void txtAltura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtAltura.Text != ""){foreach (char c in txtAltura.Text.ToCharArray()) txtAltura_KeyPress(sender, new KeyPressEventArgs(c));}
            }
```

Hope make it better.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" exactly mean? Does it focus on a different control? Check the `Tab Index` property on each textbox and make sure they're in order.

Comment: I like to think I know a lot about parsing, but "Make code for multiple textbox when press Enter send command Tab better" is a bit beyond my abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its windows form app can use this, this will replace tab key press with Enter key

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (int)m.WParam == 13)
                {
                    this.ProcessTabKey(true);
                }
                return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
            }
```

Comment: I also have to repeat this on each textbox to check if all codes was filled and update statusbar:

            private void txtAltura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                testePreenchidoecalculo();
            }
    
            private void txtLargura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                testePreenchidoecalculo();
            }
    
            private void txtProfundidade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                testePreenchidoecalculo();
            }

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're trying to figure out a way to assign event handlers to multiple textbox controls and don't want to write a handler for each one. If that's the case, try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
    }
}

void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
      e.Handled = true;
      SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
   }
}
```

This will assign a handler to each textbox control on the form.

Answer (score 0):

That worked perfectly well.

I also have to repeat this on each textbox to check if all codes was filled and update statusbar:

```
        private void txtAltura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testePreenchidoecalculo();
        }

        private void txtLargura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testePreenchidoecalculo();
        }

        private void txtProfundidade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testePreenchidoecalculo();
        }
```

Its possible to make it better ?